Is there a way to tell maven that dependencies are coming from the same maven project?
I have a multi-module maven project that can be simplified as follow:
* root
|- moduleA
\- moduleB (depending on moduleA)

I want to run several commands on the structure of the project, such as mvn exec:exec or mvn dependency:tree. While I know that I can run this command when the project has been built at least, I would like to run this even before the first build - for CI purposes, as the build phase takes some time.
With my current configuration - a standard config referring to dependencies using their groupid:artifactid - I got errors like:

Could not resolve dependencies for project abc:moduleB:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: abc:moduleA:jar:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (absent)

This is fair, because they don't exist in my local repository.
So my question is: Is there a way to teach maven that these dependencies are relative to each other, and located in the same project?
Thank you

Funny enough, the command mvn dependency:tree does work without a build, as well as mvn versions:set, but not mvn exec:exec.

First why do you need exec:exec to be run before?

It happens that I use exec:exec to print information about the Maven module, like the expression ${project.basedir} ${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}. However, this is beyond my question. I have explored other maven plugins, such as maven help providing help:evaluate, or just building my own plugin.
But this question focuses on the way to instruct maven about the dependencies between modules. I prefer staying on that particular question, possibly removing any ref to other plugins, than trying to solve my special problem

And if by before, you meant calling it before doing a full build, in a CI environment where you must restart find from scratch, I wanted to avoid a full-build taking 10-15 mins (very large project) only to gather some info about the modules. Hence my question, though this is beyond the original OP, focusing on ways to configure maven.

Unfortunately that does not answer my question: Why do you need to do exec whatever before a Maven build? What is the purpose? The dependencies between the modules is defined by it's dependencies... but if you call exec:... that means you are not using the life cycle which implies there is no "so called reactor" which has the information about the relationship between the modules.....otherwise you have to read the pom files yourself...

Quoting my original answer, I use exec:exec to print information about the Maven modules in the project.
For ex, I run mvn -pl some-module -amd exec:exec -Dexec.executable -Dexec.args='${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId} to print the names and paths of submodules which depend on my submodule some-module.
This is working exactly as expected.
And if you want the very-end goal, it is to have a smart CI only running tests based on impacts of changed files in a PR.
And again, if you are bothered by my use of exec:exec, let's change to anything else. Would it change your answer?
